# how to hide table if search not match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

`table` or `thead` should automatically hide if table search match hide all `tr` elements.

[image]

I have tried this method but not work.

```
if ($("table tr:visible").length === 1) {
  $("tbody").addClass('display-hide');
}
```

or

```
$(document).each(function () {
  if ($("table tr:visible").length === 1) {
     $("tbody").addClass('display-hide');
   }
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/abilashu/m5k7av21/13/

If possible, please give a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` loop to iterate through tables then using `$(this).find("tbody tr:visible").length` get length of visible trs inside table then depending on length `addClass` or `removeClass` from tbody or thead.

**Demo Code** :

```js
class tableLiveSearch {
  constructor(table, searchable) {
    this.table = table;
    this.searchable = searchable;
    this.hide_row_list = new Array();
  }
  updateTable(search_query) {
    this.hide_row_list = this.searchTable(search_query);
    this.showAllTableRows();
    this.hideTableRows();
  }
  searchTable(search_query) {
    var temporary_list = new Array();
    var $searchable_items = $(this.table + ' ' + this.searchable);

    $searchable_items.each(function(index, value) {
      var $this_element = $(this);
      search_query = search_query.toLowerCase();
      var search_content = $this_element.text().toLowerCase();
      if (search_content.indexOf(search_query) == -1)
        temporary_list.push($this_element.parent());

    });

    return temporary_list;
  }
  showAllTableRows() {
    $(this.table + ' ' + this.searchable).each(function(index, value) {
      $(this).parent().show();
    });
  }
  hideTableRows() {
    $.each(this.hide_row_list, function(index, value) {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }
}

var searchtable = new tableLiveSearch('.search-table', '.searchable');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  searchtable.updateTable($(this).val());
  //remove class from tbody and thead
  $("thead , tbody").removeClass('display-hide')
  //loop through table
  $("table.search-table").each(function() {
    //check if the length is (hide or show
    $(this).find("tbody tr:visible").length == 0 ? $(this).find("thead , tbody").addClass('display-hide') : $(this).find("thead , tbody").removeClass('display-hide')
  })

});
```

```css
.display-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-12 mt-4">
      <form class="form">
        <input class="form-control" id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search a name..." aria-label="Search">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table search-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="searchable">Stackoverflow</td>
            <td>33</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="searchable">Google</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="searchable">Twitter</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="table search-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="searchable">Apple</td>
            <td>345</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="searchable">Banana</td>
            <td>34</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="searchable">Orange</td>
            <td>87</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks. Is class tableLiveSearch {..} this is vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. You can use this code _as is_ without needing to convert it.